# How to setup vscode settings for Python formatter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

Somehow my formatter isn't working. I pip installed yapf , but when I do `Ctrl+Shift+P` -> Format Document or `Shift + Alt + F` on a selected code, It doesn't change. I heard it auto formats on save, but that didn't work either.

I am trying to follow the guide [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting).
It mentions I should edit this part in the settings

```json
"python.formatting.yapfArgs": ["--style", "{based_on_style: chromium, indent_width: 20}"],
```

But when I search this, [this](https://snipboard.io/9sCB8H.jpg) is the only thing I see

What I am trying to do at the moment is set the indent to 4 spaces, and also adjust the max line length.

[This](https://snipboard.io/LXklRI.jpg) is what my settings look like for formatting

Comment: Can you update your images? We cannot see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems in the preference you have not set the correct "provider" for the formatting

[image]

You can also check for the file C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json (if you want to change globally) or \.vscode\settings.json (if you want to change for the current workspace only).

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: This option does not exist anymore!